# How to read part of a file into perl array and query a second file (best practice)

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am wanting to query a large file (FileA) based on the information in a second smaller file (FileB), and output the differences between the 2 files based on what is present in the smaller file (FileB).

To do this, I thought an array for each file would be best, converting each line of each array to a hash, and comparing the hashes - outputting what in FileB does not match with FileA.

FileA & FileB are both tab delimited, both contain 2 columns where the first column contains a unique number, and the second is a letter. FileA has 250,000,000 rows compared to 150 in FileB and both are sorted smallest to largest based on $1.

Based on the information present in FileB$1 I am able to know where to start/end the FileA array from/to. With this I was then trying to load the corresponding rows of FileA into an array and compare only those rows with array of FileB.

So far I have used perl to load 2 separate "fake" files into an array and compare the differences. This was with this code and example filesets:

```
open my $handle1, '<', './file1';
chomp(my @array1 = <$handle1>);
close $handle1;

open my $handle2, '<', './file2';
chomp(my @array2 = <$handle2>);
close $handle2;

my %hash;
for my $key (@array2) {
    $hash{$key}++;
}

for my $key (@array1) {
    print "Fail: $key\n" unless $hash{$key};
}
```

file1

```
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   A
5   A
6   A
7   A
8   A
9   A
```

file2

```
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   A
5   B
6   A
7   A
8   A
9   A
```

**In this example where both files have the same number of lines I get the expected output 
`"Fail: 5 B"`

When file lengths do not match however, I get different results... so this was my reasoning for wanting to match the length of both files in my real example outlined above.

Based on the above perl array code working I then tried to apply this to my actual dataset, limiting the FileA array to the position detailed in FileB$1[1] and FileB$1[N] (where [N] is the last value in FileB$1

This is my code, after doing some searching on the internet I found Tie::File, which to my understanding only loads defined lines of a file into an array rather than loading the whole file. In this example I have not yet figured out how to take the the first/ last value of FileB$1 so I have explicitly stated it. Also, I ask it to print so I can see the correct lines have been found in FileA but this can be turned off once up and running.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
tie my @array, 'Tie::File', 'FileA' or die $!;
my $l = 11999;  # explicit statement
while (defined( my $line = $array[$l] )) {
    print "<$line>\n";
    last if $line =~ '12150'; #explicit statement
} continue { $l++ }

open my $handle2, '<', './FileB';
chomp(my @array2 = <$handle2>);
close $handle2;

my %hash;
for my $key (@array2) {
    $hash{$key}++;
}

for my $key (@array) {
    print "Fail: $key\n" unless $hash{$key};
}
```

With FileA and FileB looking like this:

FileA

```
1 A
2 A
...
250000000 A
```

FileB

```
12000 C
12001 C
12002 E
12003 F
12004 E
...
12150 C
```

FileA array

```
12000 C
12001 C
12002 G
12003 G
12004 G
...
12150 C
```

I would want to the FileA array to start at line 11999 (this line corresponds to FileA$1 = 12000, and based on my current code end when the line read into the array contains 12150.

Then read in FileB to an array, compare and output the differences. At the moment it takes ~ 3 minutes to load in the desired 150 lines of FileA but then the comparison of the 2 arrays never ends. By this I don't mean I don't get an output to screen, rather I am not sure the two arrays are being compared correctly and the script continues to run - this is unlike the 9 line "fake" files used above (less than a second)

Desired output would be as follows as FileB is different to FileA at these rows.

```
Fail: 12002 E
Fail: 12003 F
Fail: 12004 E
```

Comment: **Tie::File is never the answer.** For a file such as the one you presented, Tie::File will acutally use up *more* memory then reading the entire file into memory. Considering the alternative is to read a single line at a time using `while (<>)`, all it's doing is making your program 30x slower for nothing!

Comment: Can you describe, without anything about *how* to obtain it, *what* you want the results to be? Is it just the lines in fileb that don't appear in filea?

Comment: Hi, @Shawn - in a word yes. I want to count how many lines of FileB don't appear in FileA. As FileA is so large I only want to focus on the regions of FileB and see what in FileB is different from FileA at those sites in FileA... I have many thousands of small files like FileB and need to rapidly check them all for differences against FileA at their corresponding lines.

Comment: HI ikegami, I just ran it and I get "Fail: 5 B" to my screen.

Comment: My first inclination is to just use `comm -13 fileA fileB` instead of writing a custom program.

Comment: @Shawn What the OP didn't say in their comment is that there should only be output for ids in the smaller file.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong (though it prints `Fail: 5 A` rather than `Fail: 5 B`). Comments deleted.

Comment: Are the values always exactly one character long? If so, there's a way to make this amazingly fast without complicated code

Comment: @ikegami Yes... that's what the `-13` does for `comm`.

Comment: @Lloyd Do you care about knowing in *which* of these thousands of FileB's a mismatch happens in, or only that there is a mismatch at all?

Comment: in the second column? yes.

Comment: I care if there is a mismatch, and how many mismatches per FileB. if there is 1, 2, ... 20 etc. ?

Comment: Cool, `comm -13` does indeed do the trick.

Comment: Though `comm` requires its input files to be sorted *lexicographically*, not *numerically* like these seem to be. So much for that idea. You can always resort the files, I suppose.

Comment: ok, brilliant. I am clearly over complicating things! I'll have a look at comm and take it from there. Thanks for the advice/ comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $qfn1 = './file1';
my $qfn2 = './file2';

my %lookup;
{
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn2)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn2\": $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      chomp;
      my ($id, $val) = split /\t/;
      $lookup{$id} = $val;
   }
}

{
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn1)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn1\": $!\n");

   while (<$fh>) {
      chomp;
      my ($id, $val) = split /\t/;
      print "Fail: $id\t$val\t$lookup{$id}\n"
         if exists($lookup{$id})
         && $val ne $lookup{$id};
   }
}
```

Ways to speed this up:

- Stop reading once you've found the largest id from the smaller file.
- Perform a binary search on the larger file to find the right block. This is a lot more complicated.

---

Because the following is true, we know exactly where the block of interest is located in the larger file:

- The numbers in both files are sorted.
- There are no gaps in the numbers in the second file.
- The value is always exactly one character.

As such, the following efficient solution presents itself:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Fcntl qw( SEEK_SET );

sub offset {
   my ($id) = @_;
   --$id;
   my $offset = $id * ( length($id)+3 );
   for my $i (1..length($id)-1) {
      $offset -= ( 10**$i - 1 ) ;
   }
   return $offset;
}

my $qfn1 = './file1';
my $qfn2 = './file2';

{
   open(my $fh1, '<', $qfn1)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn1\": $!\n");
   open(my $fh2, '<', $qfn2)
      or die("Can't open \"$qfn2\": $!\n");

   my $line2 = <$fh2>;
   if (defined($line2)) {
      seek($fh1, offset(( $line2 =~ /^([^\t]*)/ )[0]), SEEK_SET)
         or die $!;

      while (defined($line2)) {
         defined( my $line1 = <$fh1> )
            or die "Premature EOF";

         if ($line1 ne $line2) {
            chomp($line1);  my ($id1, $val1) = split(/\t/, $line1);
            chomp($line2);  my ($id2, $val2) = split(/\t/, $line2);
            die "Id mismatch" if $id1 ne $id2;
            say join "\t", $id1, $val1, $val2;
         }

         $line2 = <$fh2>;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, ikegami I shall test this now - a binary search on a specific block is probably what I need to do but being a noob I have no clue. Would you be able to link me to any reference material?

Comment: Why? How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Also would you mind commenting with # what each little bit does - just briefly if possible!

Comment: There are two key lines: 1) `$lookup{$id} = $val;`, which stores the value in the hash, keyed by id. 2) and the `print if ...`, which prints the message if the id was in the smaller file (`exists($lookup{$id})`) and if the value is different in both files (`$val ne $lookup{$id}`)

Comment: I have 1000s of files like FileB so the quicker the better for the entire fileset. E.g. if it takes 5 minutes for one FileB then I'll have to think about rewriting it again.

Comment: The binary search algorithm is described on Wikipedia. To move around the file, one would use `seek`. To find the next id in the file, read a line and discard it (since you might have seeked into the middle of one), then read a line to get the id.

Comment: It took 1 minute 30 seconds to generate the 250000000 records on my relatively slow shared web host. The solution I posted should take about the same time.

Comment: Hi ikegami - this is still running... but based on the comments above I'm going to try and do what I want with comm first and take it from there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want the count of records in FileB that aren't in FileA. First, a few non-perl approaches:

Using the [comm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) utility, which finds lines in common or not in common between two files. This is complicated slightly by it requiring that its input be sorted in lexicographic order, not numeric like your files come in.

```
# Sort the big FileA once and re-use
sort FileA > FileA.sorted 
# Print all lines of FileB that don't appear in FileA
comm -13 FileA.sorted <(sort FileB) 
# Print the total number of these lines
comm -13 FileA.sorted <(sort FileB) | wc -l
```

Or an `awk` version that prints the number of mismatches that is slightly optimized for numerically sorted files:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { max = $1; b[$1] = $2; next }
     FNR == NR { if ($1 > max) max = $1; b[$1] = $2; next }
     $1 > max { exit }
     $1 in b && b[$1] != $2 { count++ }
     END { print count }' FileB FileA # Note order of arguments
```

this translates into the equivalent but more verbose perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Usage: perl foo.pl FileA FileB

use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

my $max;
my %b;
open my $fileb, "<", $ARGV[1];
while (<$fileb>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split;
    $b{$k} = $v;
    if ($. > 1) {
        $max = $k if $k > $max;
    } else {
        $max = $k;
    }
}

my $count = 0;
open my $filea, "<", $ARGV[0];
while (<$filea>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split;
    last if $k > $max;
    $count++ if exists $b{$k} && $b{$k} ne $v;
}
print "$count\n";
```

The next step would be a version that takes multiple different FileB arguments and only uses one pass over FileA to check them all:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Usage: perl foo.pl FileA FileB ...

use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

my $fileaname = shift;    
my $max;
my %b;
my %filebcounts;
for my $filebname (@ARGV) {
    $filebcounts{$filebname} = 0;
    open my $fileb, "<", $filebname;
    while (<$fileb>) {
        my ($k, $v) = split;
        push @{$b{$k}}, [ $filebname, $v ];
        if (defined $max) {
            $max = $k if $k > $max;
        } else {
            $max = $k;
        }
    }
}

my $count = 0;
open my $filea, "<", $fileaname;
while (<$filea>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split;
    last if $k > $max;
    if (exists $b{$k}) {
        for my $fileb (@{$b{$k}}) {
            $filebcounts{$$fileb[0]}++ if $$fileb[1] ne $v;
        }
    }
}

for my $fileb (sort keys %filebcounts) {
    print "$fileb: $filebcounts{$fileb}\n";
}
```